# Issue connection to CRM using connection string

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

We have a crm online instance and have some task scheduler jobs that connects using the crm using the tooling connection string.

We are changing the application users from an online user (username@orgname.onmicrosoft.com) to an AD user (username@domain.com) but we are receiving error messages when we try the new user in the connection string.

I tried changing the AuthType attribute of the connection string but keep getting errors.

The current connection string is:

```
Url=https://orgname.crm4.dynamics.com;
Username= username@orgname.onmicrosoft.com;
Password=pass;
ClientId=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX;
AuthType=OAuth;
RedirectUri=http://localhost:55162/;
```

After changing the connection string to:

```
Url=https://orgname.crm4.dynamics.com;
Username= username@domain.com;
Password=pass;
ClientId=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX;
AuthType=OAuth;
RedirectUri=http://localhost:55162/;
```

The OrganizationWebProxyClient attribute is null and in the LastCrmError we are getting

```
ERROR REQUESTING Token FROM THE Authentication context - General ADAL Error
parsing_ws_metadata_exchange_failed: Parsing WS metadata exchange failed => The ';' character, hexadecimal value 0x3B, cannot be included in a name. Line 14, position 223.Unable to connect to CRM: The ';' character, hexadecimal value 0x3B, cannot be included in a name. Line 14, position 223.
Unable to Login to Dynamics CRMOrganizationWebProxyClient is null
```

When I change the AuthType to Office365 I'm getting the error:

```
Unable to connect to CRM: CData elements not valid at top level of an XML document. Line 1, position 3.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://adfs.domain.com/adfs/services/trust/mex'. => CData elements not valid at top level of an XML document. Line 1, position 3.Unable to Login to Dynamics CRM
Unable to Login to Dynamics CRMOrganizationWebProxyClient is null
```

And when I change the AuthType to AD I'm getting the error:

```
Unable to login to Dynamics CRM, Error was : 
Data[0] = "The provided uri did not return any Service Endpoints!
{0}"
Data[1] = ""
Data[0] = "The provided uri did not return any Service Endpoints!
{0}"
Data[1] = ""Unable to Login to Dynamics CRM
Unable to Login to Dynamics CRMOrganizationWebProxyClient is null
```

The new user name and password are correct since I'm able to login to the crm using the browser without any issue.

Comment: easiest way will be to create an App Registration, inside the connection string just put clientid and clientsecret and update the nuget packages

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this, out of curiosity?